# Problem in alphabetically display on child pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a PageSidebar.js component which lists the child pages alphabetically.

[image]

But when I click in a child page, the alphabetical order is not performed.

[image]

I tried everything but I couldn't make it work. The code in Github:

https://github.com/rcapdepaula/problema-p-gina-filho

Comment: rest of code? data undefined until loaded

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: `if(!data) return null;` ... use map to render content ... react can't render arrays/objects

Comment: `{data.wpPage.wpChildren}` - **don't do that !! ... pass data as props, render only components or tags !!** ... render children only when they are already components/tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{parentChlidren
  .map(child => (
    <li key={child.id}>
      <Link to={child.uri} activeClassName="sidebar-highlighted">
        <span> {child.title} </span>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))
  .sort((x, y) => {
    if (x.title < y.title) {
      return -1
    } else {
      return 1
    }
  })}
```

You are sorting a `HTML`, try to sort first and after that, map to return it

Comment: Man, that's right, So many days in vain ... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Could you also try using `localeCompare()` instead of manually checking the strings?

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_non-ascii_characters

Comment: I tried all sorts of sort () and localeCompare () functions but I'm not getting it to work.